# find regex pattern in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

```
some text i dont care about, some_text_I_want,
<bunch of spaces> some_text_I_want,
```

I want my pattern to match second line, not first line.  Basically wherever `some_text_I_want,` is not preceeded with a `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
\([^ ,]\|^\)\s*some_text_I_want
```

?

The bit in brackets looks for a character that isn't a space or a comma, or alternatively the start of the line.  Then there is an allowance for any spaces and the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

A negative lookbehind assertion is straightforward:

```
\v(,\s*)@<!some_text_I_want
```